# Bind more than one property to a Xamarin ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

Is there a way to add more than one binding to multiple properties inside a ListView?
I currently have this code inside my xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
                            <Button Text="{Binding Button}"></Button>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

For now I can bind the text inside the Label with this C# code:

```
ItemsListView.ItemsSource = names; //names being a string array
```

The code above works with the Label but I can't seem to find out how to bind the button text.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: `ItemSource` should be bound to a collection of objects. Then each control, label, button etc. can be bound to different properties on that object.

Comment: You can refer to Wasif Mahmood Mustafa's answer.Binding modle to `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
 <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                                <Button Text="{Binding ButtonName}"></Button>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Then make a class of both properties.

```
public class ListClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ButtonName { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize your list in your page.

```
List<ListClass> lists = new List<ListClass>()
        {
            new ListClass(){ Name = "John" , ButtonName = "Submit"},
            new ListClass(){ Name = "Alexa" , ButtonName = "Click"}
        };
```

And finally bind it to the ItemsSource.

```
ItemsListView.ItemsSource = lists;
```